# pd.core.groupby.data error no numeric types to aggregate - ok for max/min, not ok for mean/std

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I read many questions related to the "pandas.core.groupby.data error no numeric types to aggregate" error but I was not able to find an answer to the problem I am facing.

[image]

Namely, I can perform some operations on my `.groupby` construct, such as `.max()`, `.count()`... but operations like `.mean()`, `.std` raise the above mentioned error.

I saw in other threads that it could have to do with the datatype, but I am dealing with `int64`, which I believe are fine. In fact, I can call `.mean()` on the column I am interested in if I call it without grouping first (see second line below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem `holding_time` columns is not numeric, so first need convert:

```
df['holding_time'] = df['holding_time'].astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['holding_time'] = df['holding_time'].astype(float)
```

If solution failed because mixed values - numeric with strings, need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert unparseable values to `NaN`s:

```
df['holding_time'] = pd.to_numeric(df['holding_time'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: After casting the column that way it works, thanks a lot. Quick question though: I was convinced that the `holding_time` column was an numeric, since: 1, can compute its mean when not grouping, 2. `dtype` is displyed to be "int64" when I group and call e.g., `sum`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: It is weird, so before converting `print (df['holding_time'].dtype)` is numeric? And groupby change it to non numeric?

Comment: hmm actually, `print (df['holding_time'].dtype)` tells me it is an `int 32` ! I am more and more puzzled. I thought it was an ìnt64`... Do you know what this all means?

Comment: I dont know, if it is numeric, `mean` should working nice. Only one idea - what is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())` ?

Comment: Thanks for this. I have pandas 0.17.1.

Comment: Is possible upgrade? Last version is `0.22.0`